# Implementating GridLayout v7 for API 8,

Tags: android, android-layout, compatibility, xml-namespaces, android-gridlayout

I have a problem with a layout which uses a GridLayout widget from Android Support Library v7 `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`.

I have already added the external JAR from this path:

> `<sdk_folder>\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout`

To my project properties: `Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` tab.

And also, in the same Properties window in "Order and Export" tab, I marked the box of the imported JAR on the list.

But when I use this widget in my layout, it gives me the next errors in the GridLayout:

> -error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'columnCount' in package 'com.mwm.internews'
>   
>   -error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'rowCount' in package 'com.mwm.internews'

Also I am getting the same errors for each one of the child views contained in this GridLayout (I have **three TextViews** inside this GridLayout who are throwing the same errors)

My project package name is `com.mwm.internews`. Here is the XML file with the issue and I have only put one of the three TextViews metioned above for reference:

element_page_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/White"
   android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rba_rating_element_page_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/element_ratingbar"
        android:rating="5.0"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rba_rating_element_page_2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/glo_content_rating_element_page_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imv_image_element_page_2"
            grid:columnCount="2"
            grid:rowCount="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@color/Transparent"
                android:text="@string/txt_text_rating_element_page_2"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkGray"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <TextView
                ... />

            <TextView
                ... />
        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Here are the errors for the first TextView that are repeated also on the next 2 TextViews:

> -error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_column' in package 'com.mwm.internews'
>   
>   -error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_gravity' in package 'com.mwm.internews'
>   
>   -error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_row' in package 'com.mwm.internews'

I been searching on many questions like this and followed solution steps posted for each one.... with no success.
What am I doing wrong??? What am I missing on my XML file???

Thanks in advance for helping me with this problem....

Answer (score 2):

> I have already added the external JAR from this path:
>
> \extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout
>
> To my project properties: Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries tab.
>   And also, in the same Properties window in "Order and Export" tab, I marked the box of the imported JAR on the list.

None of that is correct.

First, never add a JAR that way in an Eclipse Android project, for any JAR. JARs just get copied into `libs/` on Eclipse.

However, `gridlayout-v7` is an Android library project, not just a JAR. There is a [separate set of instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) for adding an Android library project to your application project.

Comment: So, what I have to do only is to copy the JAR file from path `<sdk_folder>\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout` and then paste it in `libs/` on Eclipse??? Is that the correct way???

Anyway, I have done this way and errors keep remaining.... any idea??

Comment: @Ayuchuco: No, you need to click on the hyperlink in the last paragraph of my answer and follow the instructions. Here is another copy of that link: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res You will see that there are separate instructions for Eclipse and Android Studio. You are using Eclipse, so click "Using Eclipse" to fold open that portion of the instructions.

Comment: I checked the link you've provided and I have done the steps mentioned for Eclipse. I get more errors: 
Following the steps, I've got an imported project named "android-support-v7-gridlayout" but it has on its icon a red admiration mark. And when I add this project library as part of my main project, it also gets the same red admiration mark icon. Here is the error:

`The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'`

What is the cause for this error??

Comment: @Ayuchuco: That's a problem with the tools update that came out yesterday. I would recommend putting Android aside for a few days and see if there are updates to the Android SDK (through the SDK Manager) and Eclipse early next week. Or, if you cannot wait, you can try Tor Norbye's workarounds as suggested [in his comment on a tracking issue for the tools bugs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#c12).

Comment: Yes, indeed!!! In fact I recently made an update this morning to the Android SDK and Eclipse. I wouldn't have made this update :(
It's not very urgent, so I'll wait till an update of the tools is uploaded.

Comment: @Ayuchuco: Yes, this week's tools update (and, to a lesser extent, the L Developer Preview) have had quite a few problems. I am hoping everything gets fixed next week.